# Timestamp one hour short

Tags: php, timestamp

I am trying to resolve a time entry bug I've been having. The first timestamp in the string below equates to `Sunday 11/02/14 00:00` if we add 24 hours to it as shown below, we get `Monday 11/03/14 00:00` right? If we add 13 hours to it, as shown below, we should get `11/03/14 13:00`, I would think!

Although, not sure why this keeps calculating as `11/03/14 12:00`, any ideas as to why this is ?

```
$start_time = $start_date + ($day * 24 * 60 * 60) + ($hours * 60 * 60) + ($minutes * 60);
```

Variables Printed out

```
$start_time = 1414900800 + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60) + (13 * 60 * 60) + (00 * 60) = 1415034000 //converted to readable date: 11-03-2014 12:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting these results because of the Daylight Savings Time switch between 11/02/2014 and 11/03/2014, you are loosing an hours worth of time based on your time zone selected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Shouldn't epoch account for this ? Is there a way to make such a script daylight savings proof ?

Answer (score 0):

try date_default_timezone_set:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); //uses daylight savings
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT-8');           //does not use daylight savings
```

with the desired timezone. Timezones are at http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php. Set it  before any calls to date(), strtotime(), etc.